# Google Calendar API V3 - Default or Primary Calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm attempting to use VBA to access the Google Calendar API V3. I can't figure out how to determine which calendar a new event should be written to by default. Is there no such thing as a default or primary calendar under V3 of the Google Calendar API?

Will the CalendarID for the default calendar always be the user's email address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, no, the email address is not the default CalendarID. You can user "primary" as the default CalendarID. If you want, you can get a list of all the user's Calendar ID's and even create/delete calendars. Check out https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList

Answer (score 4):

you can just use the string `"primary"` for the CalendarID property to get the default calendar